# PHP 7 error con un array de semana

Tags: php, php7

no es posible crear un **array** `$dia` en que vaya guardando los dias de la semanas tal que asi :

```
$dia[] = "Lunes";
$dia[] = "Martes";
$dia[] = "Miercoles";
$dia[] = "Jueves";
$dia[] = "Viernes";
```

Y luego cuando quiera acceder a una determinada posicion simplemente poner un **indice** dentro de los **corchetes** `[]`  por ejemeplo asi:

esto : `$dia[2]` deberia ser `Miercoles`.

¿Por que **no funciona**?

Mi **LOG ERROR** (son **dos errores**) :

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for`



`Error: [] operator not supported for strings`

Comment: Lo que comentas es perfectamente posible. Tienes que estar cometiendo algún fallo en otro lado. Puedes poner información sobre el error que te da por favor?

Comment: Si, ahora mismo edito la pregunta e inserto informacion adicional.

Comment: En [`rextester`](https://rextester.com) con `PHP Version => 7.0.8` tu código funciona perfectamente. Aunque no está mal irse acostumbrando en PHP a no usar variables sin declararlas previamente.

Comment: Conincido con @A.Cedano. La única forma de que tu código falle, es porque `$dia` sea una cadena **antes** de hacer `$dia[]=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Todavía están ocurriendo cambios dentro de las mismas sub-versiones de PHP 7. Lo que ocurre aquí es un claro ejemplo de ello.

Tu código funciona en PHP 7.0, pero a partir de PHP 7.1 terminará en un error.

[En el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.incompatible.php#migration71.incompatible.array-order), y [en las notas de contribución del mismo](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration71.incompatible.php#120221) se expone un caso parecido parecido, sólo que en el código se usa una asignación por referencia. Esto funcionaba en PHP 7.0, pero no en PHP 7.1+. [Ver también aquí](https://3v4l.org/frbUc) una comparación sobre el resultado según diferentes versiones de PHP.

[Aquí se expone otro ejemplo](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration71.incompatible.php#120845), donde este código funciona en PHP 7.0:

```
<?php
    $a = "";
    $a[] = "hello world";
    var_dump($a);
?>
```

Pero en PHP 7.1+ arroja un error fatal.

O esto, que funciona diferente entre PHP 7.0 y PHP 7.1:

```
<?php
    $a = "";
    $a[0] = "hello world";
    var_dump($a);
    // 7.1: string(1) "h"
    // pre-7.1: array(1) {  [0]=>  string(11) "hello world" }
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    $a = "";
    $a[5] = "hello world";
    var_dump($a);
    // 7.1: string(6) "     h"
    // pre-7.1: array(1) {  [0]=>  string(11) "hello world" }
?>
```

¿Por qué motivo? Porque `$a` se declaró como una cadena y luego intentó usarse como un array.

---

### Conclusión

La tendencia es que PHP se haga cada vez más restrictivo ([ver aquí diferencias entre versiones y sub-versiones de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/appendices.php)). Durante mucho tiempo PHP con su permisividad nos acostumbró a ciertas malas prácticas que son impensables en otros lenguajes (como el caso de `$a` de más arriba).

No hay que alarmarse, sino ponerse manos a la obra desde ya, adoptado buenas prácticas como la de no usar una variable sin antes declararla, o no cambiar arbitrariamente entre tipos de variables.

Para obligarnos a ello, [entre sus nuevas características más relevantes](https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/5-new-features-php-7) PHP 7 tiene un modo estricto, que sería bueno activar en todos nuestros programas que escribamos en la versión 7. Es una sola línea, debe ser la primera, al principio del script:

```
declare(strict_types=1);
```

Comment: Estupendo!, realmente, estaba usando una version de **PHP** `7.1+` . Lo que pasa esque no le di mayor importancia, muchas gracias por la aclaracion. Sabia que PHP era **permisivo** pero no sabia que podia llegar eso a suponer un problema. Muchas gracias Cedano

Comment: No se si me aconsejas que use la **version** `7` o `7.1+`

Comment: @josanangel según he leído eso está dando problemas a veces serios incluso en plataformas muy usadas como por ejemplo Wordpress, porque hay escrito código a ese estilo *permisivo*  y como ahora en muchos casos eso terminará en un error fatal la cosa se pone seria. Por eso he recomendado ser estrictos y si es posible empezar a corregir cosas en nuestro código antiguo en la medida de la posible.

Comment: @josanangel *«No se si me aconsejas que use la version 7 o 7.1+»*  No, no te aconsejo que vuelvas a la versión 7.0, porque de todos modos parece que PHP se decidió a corregir ciertas malas prácticas, lo que te aconsejo es lo contrario, que seas lo más estricto posible escribiendo tu código, para adaptarte así al camino emprendido por PHP 7 y que me parece correcto.

Comment: Perfecto, ademas me viene mejor pues estoy aprendiendo ahora **PHP** asi que no me supondra un gran problema el **despegarme** de malas practicas en `PHP` puesto que no me dio tiempo de obtenerlas. Muchas gracias, muy amable.

Answer (score 3):

Si puedes hacer eso, solo asegurate de inicializar el array:

```
$dia   =  array(); // inicilizar array

$dia[] = "Lunes";
$dia[] = "Martes";
$dia[] = "Miercoles";
$dia[] = "Jueves";
$dia[] = "Viernes";
```

Comment: Aunque es una buena práctica no es en absoluto necesario inicializar el array. El error que le da no puede ser pos eso.

Comment: Esto me lo soluciona, pero como dice @cooper no es necesario hacerlo

Comment: Puedes validar tu código en [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/) con la versión 7 de PHP y muestra lo que necesitas sin declarar la variable `$dia   =  array();`.